# How can I create a histogram of the values and their count without using the hist() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot figure out a way to print the histogram of the values in format of range. I wanted to write a code to output the items and counts(multiply 'x') ). if a item does not exist, output will ''
Here is what I wrote so far:

```
item=['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
max=15
min=0
def histogram( count, item ):
    i=0
    if(max-min<=5):
        for n in count:
            output = ''
            times = n
            while( times > 0 ):
              output += '*'
              times = times - 1
            #print(item[i],output)
            print(f'{item[i]:<10}',output)
            i+=1  
    elif(max-min>5):
        #print the histogram in range of 5s
histogram( count, item )
```

Output(if the max-min<5)-this won't happen in above program since max-min is larger than 5 but I wanted to show u how it will look like if we assume max-min was less than 5:

```
15         *
14         *
13         *
12         *
11         ***
10
9
8
7         *
6
5
4         *
3
2
1
0          *
```

Output for (max-min>5)

```
10-15  *******
5-10   *
0-5    *
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for doing it this way?

Comment: For what it is worth... https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-annotate-bars-in-barplot-with-matplotlib-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaned your code up a bit. `'*'*x` will print `'*'` `x` times.

This also handles the case where the number of items is not a multiple of 5.

```
item=['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
maxi=15
mini=0
def histogram( count, item ):
    if(maxi-mini<=5):
        for i, c in zip(item, count):
            output = '*'*c
            print(f'{i:<10}',output)
    elif(maxi-mini>5):
        for index in range(0, len(item), 5):
            #print the histogram in range of 5s
            end_index = min(index+4, len(item)-1) # this is to handle if number of items is not divisible by 5
            range_str = f'{item[end_index]}-{item[index]}'
            output = '*'*sum(count[index:end_index+1])
            print(range_str, output)
histogram( count, item )
```

This prints:

```
11-15 *******
6-10 *
1-5 *
0-0 *
```

It would work better if we invert the `item` and `count` lists first with

```
item = list(reversed(item))
count = list(reversed(count))
```

and tweaking the function a bit:

```
item=['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
maxi=15
mini=0
def histogram( count, item ):
    if(maxi-mini<=5):
        for i, c in zip(item, count):
            output = '*'*c
            print(f'{i:<10}',output)
    elif(maxi-mini>5):
        for index in range(0, len(item), 5):
            #print the histogram in range of 5s
            end_index = min(index+4, len(item)-1) # this is to handle if number of items is not divisible by 5
            range_str = f'{item[index]}-{item[end_index]}'
            output = '*'*sum(count[index:end_index+1])
            print(range_str, output)
```

This prints

```
0-4 **
5-9 *
10-14 ******
15-15 *
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, there is an error says "int object is not callable" when I tried to tun this code

Comment: Fixed, since `min=0` overrides the builtin `min` function. Renamed `min` variable to `mini`.

Answer (score 2):

`range` takes `step` like `range(start, end, step)`. You can use step to tell to go a step of `5` like `15-10`, `10-5`, `5-0`

```py
item=['15', '14', '13', '12', '11', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1', '0']
count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
max_=15
min_=0
def histogram( count, item ):
    i=0
    if(max_-min_<=5):
        for n in count:
            output = ''
            times = n
            while( times > 0 ):
                output += '*'
                times = times - 1
            #print(item[i],output)
            print(f'{item[i]:<10}',output)
            i+=1  
    elif(max_-min_>5):
        for i in range(0, len(item)-5, 5):
            label = item[i] + "-" + item[i+5]
            print(f'{ label:<10}','*' * sum(count[i: i+5]))
        
histogram(count, item )
```

```
15-10      *******
10-5       *
5-0        *
```

Comment: What if `max` is 16?